# Customize the <img title> tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering is it possible to customize the tooltip that we get after setting the title attribute in an img tag? Now I get a standard rectangle with blue background with text on it and what I'd want to get is my own image (lets say something that looks like a cloud) with text on it. Is it possible with css or js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need javascript for that. try [this here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) or [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip)
Or you can roll your own. But basically there is no way to do it directly in html (dont know about htm5/css3).

Comment: The flowplayer tooltips are great!

Answer (score 1):

Create your own!  You can simply create a hidden div in your HTML, then when someone hovers over the image, show your div instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create a custom tooltip, I would recommend [this](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/). It shows you, in detail, how to create your own tooltips in js, which are CSS driven and can be easily reused.

Additionally, if you are using a framework, things get even easier. For example there are numerous [jQuery tooltip plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/). These allow you to make your tooltips appear on the mouseover of any element.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend [Tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/). Really easy to use, can be used on any element that supports the `title` attribute and has many cool features and looks.